# Laravel Blade double curly brace not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

By reading the Laravel documentation, I've understood that I should be able to use `{{ }}` to escape my strings. However, by doing this, I'm getting an error, but the string works fine if I run `{!! !!}`. Is there anything I'm missing in my code?

A complete view of the code blade file (login.blade.php)

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="kt-grid kt-grid--ver kt-grid--root">
   <div class="kt-grid kt-grid--hor kt-grid--root  kt-login kt-login--v3 kt-login--signin" id="kt_login">
    <div class="kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid kt-grid kt-grid--hor" style="background-image: url({{ asset('assets/media//bg/bg-3.jpg);">
     <div class="kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid kt-login__wrapper">
      <div class="kt-login__container">
       <div class="kt-login__logo">
        <a href="#">
         <img src="assets/media/logos/logo-5.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="kt-login__signin">
        
        <div class="kt-login__head">
         <h3 class="kt-login__title">Sign In To Account</h3>
        </div>

                                <form class="kt-form" method="post" action="/login">
         
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
         
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" autocomplete="off">
         </div>

         <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
         </div>
         
         @if ($errors->any())

          @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
           <p>{!! error !!}</p>
          @endforeach
         
         @endif

         <div class="row kt-login__extra">
          <div class="col">
           <label class="kt-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
            <span></span>
           </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col kt-align-right">
           <a href="javascript:;" id="kt_login_forgot" class="kt-login__link">Forget Password ?</a>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="kt-login__actions">
          <button id="kt_login_signin_submit" class="btn btn-brand btn-elevate kt-login__btn-primary">Sign In</button>
         </div>
        </form>
       </div>

       <div class="kt-login__account">
        <span class="kt-login__account-msg">
         Don't have an account yet ?
        </span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="" id="kt_login_signup" class="kt-login__account-link">Sign Up!</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

**Error**

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) syntax error, unexpected 't' (T_STRING),
>   expecting ',' or ')' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php) Previous
>   exceptions syntax error, unexpected 't' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or
>   ')' (0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 'error' a variable with double brackets. It's considered an undefined constant otherwise.

```php
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach
```

You also need to add the right curly brace and the missing right single quote for the URL in the `asset()` helper function.

```php
<div class="kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid kt-grid kt-grid--hor"
    style="background-image: url({{ asset('assets/media/bg/bg-3.jpg') }}">
```